# How do I kill all processes except PID 1?

Tags: process, kill

I want to kill all processes on a system except for PID 1.

I am currently using `pgrep -l . | awk "{if (\$1 != 1) print \$1}" | xargs -n 1 kill -s INT`.

`awk` is used to exclude the process with PID 1

If I run the command on alpine linux (which uses `sh`), I get:

```
# pgrep -l . | awk "{if (\$1 != 1) print \$1}" | xargs -n 1 kill -s INT
kill: can't kill pid 265: No such process
```

I believe `PID 256` is from `awk`.

Is there a clean way (using utilities that should be available across most linux systems) to kill all processes except for `PID 1`?

Comment: That simply makes no sense.  Many processes running are essential.  What are you really trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I am using this to develop within a docker container. When code is updated, I want to kill all processes (such as tests that are currently running) and then rerun those tests.

Comment: Since you apparently don't want to reboot, you should keep track of the processes you create that need to be restarted.

Comment: Why not restart the container instead?

Comment: Restarting the container takes a few seconds longer (which is not good for developer productivity). Also, needing to reattach to stdin etc increases the complexity.

Comment: complexity is a problem that scripts can solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux at least,

```
kill -- -1
```

Will send the SIGTERM signal to every process it can  except for the calling process (so the process running that `kill` command which could be the shell if `kill` is built-in there (it usually is on POSIX shells) or the process running a standalone `kill` command) and the process of pid 1.

Note that it does it as part of the `kill()` system call, so it's more reliable than using commands like `pkill` or `killall` (or the traditional `killall` command sometimes found as `killall5` on Linux traditionally used for that) that first list the processes and then kill them as those would miss the processes that have been spawned in the mean time.

So it sounds like exactly what you want.

```
trap '' TERM # ignore SIGTERM ourselves though it wouldn't be needed 
             # in most shells
kill -- -1
sleep 1 # leave processes some time to exit cleanly on SIGTERM
kill -s KILL -- -1 # removes the remaining processes or those 
                   # that have started since without giving them
                   # a chance to clean-up.
exit
```

Should kill everything but the process of id 1.

You can experiment with it by running:

```
unshare --mount-proc -mpf
```

That starts a shell in a separate pid and mount namespace (with a new /proc (as used by `ps`/`pkill`/`killall`)) where that shell has pid 1.

Outside of Linux, `kill -- -1` should work on every system at killing most processes, but the list of processes that are exempt from the killing can vary from system to system.

Answer (score 0):

*Can* you?  Yes.  *Should* you?  under nearly all circumstances, no.  But:

`init` ignores SIGTERM on Linux, explicitly.  So you could simply do `killall -TERM '*'`.

Comment: Running `killall -TERM *` doesn't kill anything for me: `killall: bin: no process killed
killall: src: no process killed`. `ps` confirms that no process was killed.

Comment: F21: That's because shell expansion happens. Try doing killall -TERM '*'

Comment: @theblazehen, at least with the `killall` from psmisc on Linux, `killall '*'` returns with a `*: no process found` message as arguments are not meant to be patterns. With that version of `killall` however, you can use `-r` for the argument  to be taken as a regexp, so it behaves more like `pkill` (the companion command of `pgrep` used by the OP). So `killall -r '^'` or `pkill '^'`. SIGTERM is the default signal, you don't need -TERM.

Comment: There are many implementations of `init` on Linux, whether they ignore SIGTERM will vary with implementations. From a `grep SigIgn /proc/1/status` on my system using systemd, SIGPIPE is the only signal that it ignores. It doesn't matter anyway, as for processes of pid 1 on Linux, signals are ignored if they are not otherwise _handled_ by the application.